# Sunspot solr pagination not working with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari, sunspot-solr

The controller Actions

```
def search_leads
            @search = Sunspot.search(Lead) do |searcher|
                searcher.all do
                    fulltext params[:email], :fields => :email
                    fulltext params[:name], :fields => [:first_name, :last_name]
                end
                searcher.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
            end
            @leads = @search.results

            respond_to do |format|
                if (params[:email].present? || params[:name].present? ) and (current_user.credits > 0)
                    format.html { redirect_to search_leads_path }
                    format.js { }
                else 
                    format.html { redirect_to new_search_path }
                end
            end
        end
```

search_leads.js.erb

```
$(".search_results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'search/search_results') %>");
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@search.hits, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

HTMl

```
<div id="paginator">
      <%= paginate @search.hits, remote: true %>
</div>
```

Pagination buttons appear in results, but i am not able to scroll through pages. When clicking on next pages, no call goes to solr.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, the issue is `remote: true` on `paginate`, just update like below

Remove `remote: true` from `paginate` and it will be on the `partial` e.g `search_results.html.erb`

```
<%= paginate @search.hits %>
```

and the main file e.g `search_leads.html.erb` add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.pagination > a').attr('data-remote', 'true');
    });
</script>
```

the `.pagination > a` is selector if this not working then just find the selector from browser console then use this.

I think this line does not require, remove this

```
$('#paginator').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@search.hits, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

and on the `search_leads.js.erb` this script also OK

```
$(".search_results").html("<%= escape_javascript(render('search/search_results')) %>");
```